# Permission denied - navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia( ); for Screen only

Tags: reactjs, browser, screen-recording

What I am trying to do:

Let the user record the screen via React.js app.

What is happening so far:

On Chrome, the browser will ask the user to pick one of the following 3 options:

- Tab (working)
- Window (working)
- Screen (not working)

The first 2 works without a problem, but the last one ("Screen") would pop up a Permission Denied.

I am using MacOS and I have checked my Security & Privacy preferences. All of "Microphone", "Camera" and "Screen Recording" permission have been given to Chrome so that should not be the issue.

Am I missing something here?